# Problems Configuring the VNC Session for RHEL 7 on Power8

Tags: vnc, redhat-enterprise-linux, vncserver

I follow http://www.linuxexplorers.com/2014/04/configure-vnc-server-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-rhel7/ to configure the RHEL 7 VNC server.

At the final configuration step "systemctl start vncserver@:1.service", I got

```
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed. See 'systemctl status vncserver@:1.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. 

journalctl -xn 
-- Logs begin at Tue 2014-09-02 14:17:21 CDT, end at Tue 2014-09-02 15:28:53 CDT. -- 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user zzz. 
-- Subject: Unit session-c2.scope has finished start-up 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
-- 
-- Unit session-c2.scope has finished starting up. 
-- 
-- The start-up result is done. 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com runuser[42609]: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session opened for user yyy 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com runuser[42609]: Warning: xx.xx.xx.com:1 is taken because of /tmp 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com runuser[42609]: Remove this file if there is no X server xx.xx.xx.com
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com runuser[42609]: A VNC server is already running as :1 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com runuser[42609]: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session closed for user yyy 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: control process exited, code=exited s 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC). 
-- Subject: Unit vncserver@:1.service has failed 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
-- 
-- Unit vncserver@:1.service has failed. 
-- 
-- The result is failed. 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state. 
Sep 02 15:28:53 xx.xx.xx.com systemd[1]: Failed to mark scope session-c2.scope as abandoned : Stale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it looks like an instance of vncserver is already running.   Now why you can't connect is probably a different question/problem

The error messages direct you to remove the /tmp lock files.     Remove those messages as recommended, and try again.

From a colleague..

Either there is already a VNC server instance running on :1, or the previous :1 VNC instance was not shut down properly.  Either way, the vncserver is checking and finding temporary files for the :1 session in the `/tmp/.X11-unix` directory.

The correct way to shut down a VNC server is to use `vncserver -kill :1`.  This should be done before the system is restarted, either manually or in a shutdown script.

If there is no VNC server :1 instance already running, clean out the `/tmp/.X11-unix` directory and try to restart the vncserver.

Answer (score 1):

```
Job for vncserver@:7.service failed. See 'systemctl status vncserver@:7.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Delete this folder:

```
rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix/
```

Its work for me.

Reference:

- [vncserver refuses to start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/vncserver-refuses-to-start)
- [How To Install and Configure VNC Remote Access for the GNOME Desktop on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-remote-access-for-the-gnome-desktop-on-centos-7?comment=42908)

Comment: Those might be useful links, but the information here was already present in the accepted answer. If you have something new to add, please edit your post.